# Setting up a microservice timeout using nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a microservice when passing in a request has certain performance requirements.  It must fail with a specific response if it takes over two seconds.  What is the best way to setup the nginx.conf file to support this?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the answer is this with the cavet that you must have the same end point for the timeout response as you have for the original microservice call.

```
server {
   listen       9000;
   server_name  localhost;

   location /microservice {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
       proxy_intercept_errors on;
       proxy_read_timeout 2s;
       error_page 504 =200 @timeout;
   }

   location @timeout {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
   }
```